# Javascript random images + back button

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a site where it randomly chooses a photo from an array, then the user can use the arrow keys to press next and load another random image, if they press back it loads the previous image. I have all of this working:

Only problem is when I press next the # of times = to the length of the array, I get an error that says Maximum call stack size exceeded.

How do I fix?

Code:

```html
var rand = imagesArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * imagesArray.length)];
var theImg = document.getElementById('gif');
theImg.src=rand;
theImg.height = 700;
theImg.width = 1920;
var usedImages = {};
var usedImagesCount = 0;
var numHistory = [];

function displayPreviousImage(){
    if (numHistory.length > 1){
      numHistory.pop();
      var num = numHistory[numHistory.length-1];
      document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];
    }
}

function displayNextImage(){

    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (imagesArray.length));

    if (!usedImages[num]){
        numHistory.push(num);
        document.canvas.src = imagesArray[num];
        usedImages[num] = true;
        if (usedImagesCount === imagesArray.length){
            usedImagesCount = 0;
   num = 0;
            usedImages = {};
   console.log("done")
        }
    } else {
        displayNextImage();
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't seem to increment `usedImagesCount` anywhere, so your condition for the code block that resets the tracking of already used images is never run and the result is an infinite recursion of `displayNextImage()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function will make an infinity loop when `usedImages` has all the posible index in your array. There is another solution that easier for you is at first lets shuffle the image array, after that just let user to browse it by the new order from 0-n. That way you will still serve the images randomly but no need to keep track of the used images.

```
function shuffle(array) {
  var m = array.length, t, i;

  // While there remain elements to shuffle…
  while (m) {

    // Pick a remaining element…
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);

    // And swap it with the current element.
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }

 return array;
}
```